# Rendering a simple chat layout

Tags: html, css

I'm currently designing a chat website. The layout will be very simple.

I want a div containing all the messages taking all the screen but 20 pixels on the bottom of the screen reserved for the form field to send messages.

The HTML code could look like this :

```
<div id="messages">
...
</div>
<input type="text" id="message" />
```

How can you render this kind of layout using CSS3 ?

Comment: ...without knowing what sort of mark-up you're working with, and what you want it to *look* like, how are we supposed to begin answering this? Bear in mind that 'HTML code could look like' *anything at all*...

Comment: I described what I want it to look like I think... See above the HTML code. It's as simple as two blocks taking all the space.

Comment: And that's it? That's the entirety of your question? How to position two blocks on a page?

Comment: The question was about how to have these two blocks extensible positionned this way right. I'm not a pro about positionning in CSS and everybody before told me absolute positionning was really bad. What's wrong with my lack of knowledge ?

Comment: Nothing at all, I just assumed that there was more to your question than you'd *expressed* in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what's wrong with using absolute positioning in this situation:

```
#messages {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

#message {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

See this jsFiddle for a [**live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LQhML/)
(colors added for clarity as to where the two elements begin/end)

Comment: I didn't think it would be so easy though it works perfectly. Thank you for your help !